# Merge one vido and images using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm want to compile one .mp4 file that contain this:

10 seconds showing mp4 file
4 seconds showing image1.jpg
...
4 seconds showing image{n}.jpg

and I want to fade between video and images .
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for
my code in c#

```
   List<string> tempimg = new List<string>();

           

            var c = (int)Math.Ceiling(item.Users.Count / 6.0);

            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                 //DO ADD IMAGE INTO tempimg

            }


            string video = "5small.mp4";

            string output = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.mp4";


            IMediaInfo mediaInfo = FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo(video).Result;
            var videoDuration = (int)mediaInfo.VideoStreams.First().Duration.TotalSeconds - 2;


            int count = tempimg.Count;

            string cmd = $@"     -i {video} " + Environment.NewLine;

            for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                cmd += $"-loop 1 -t 5 -i {tempimg[i - 1]} " + Environment.NewLine;

            cmd += "-i 1.mp3 " + Environment.NewLine;


            cmd += $@"-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 
            -filter_complex    ""  " + Environment.NewLine;

            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                cmd += $@"[{i}]format = yuva444p,fade = d = 1:t =in:alpha = 1,setpts = PTS - STARTPTS + {videoDuration + (i * 3)}  / TB[f{i - 1}];" + Environment.NewLine;

            }

            cmd += "[0][f0]overlay[bg1];" + Environment.NewLine;
            for (int i = 1; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                cmd += $@"[bg{i}][f{i}]overlay[bg{i + 1}];" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            cmd += $@"[bg{count - 1}][f{count - 1}]overlay,format = yuv420p[v]"" -map ""[v]"" -map {count + 1}:a -shortest  -movflags +faststart { output}";
```